# Resize UIScrollView's height to screen height?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, uiscrollview

[image]

Black - screen frame/size

Red - default UIScrollView's frame/size

Yellow - my button.

I want to always keep that button at the bottom. So e.g. on 3.5in screen, scrolling is available and button is at the bottom, no problem. Now, when we move to 5.5in screen, it becomes like in this image, button is not at the bottom anymore. What I am trying to do is change UIScrollView's height, but it does not work:

```
if(self.view.frame.height > contentView.frame.height)
    {
        print("fixing scroll view")
        contentView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.width, self.view.frame.height * 2)
        scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.width, self.view.frame.height * 2)
    }
```

`self.view.frame.height * 2` is just for testing. What could be wrong?

Comment: For one, why not use autolayout?  That will do this for you.  And if that is not an option, this code probably needs to be in the viewDidLayoutSubviews method to work properly.

Comment: TheValyreanGroup how could I use autolayout for this? And how could I put in viewDidLayoutSubviews? Just started learninf iOS development

Comment: do you have autolayout enabled and are you using storyboard?

Comment: yeah, autolayout enabled and using storyboard

Comment: See my answer.  And here is a great tutorial on auto layout. https://www.raywenderlich.com/115440/auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-9-part-1-getting-started-2

Answer (score 2):

Late response, but for those who need a button to stay at the bottom of the screen in a scrollview, if the content view should be the same as the screen height, try this:

1. Set ScrollView top, left, right and bottom constraints to 0 from parent
2. Set ContentView to Equal Width and Equal Height of ScrollView
3. Set ContentView top, left, right and bottom constraints to 0 from ScrollView
4. Give each element inside the scroll view some constraints, linking everything from top to bottom
5. Select one constraint between the elements and remove it, or make it low priority. I'd say to make it low priority because if you have to delete the Equal Height, the layout won't break.

[image]

Comment: Working for me :)

Answer (score 0):

With auto layout all you need to do is add pin constraints to your scrollView to each corner of the superview.

[image: Auto layout pins]

Set your 4 constraints to 0 and you'll be all set.

Comment: But then how can I set a minimum height? I need 600 minimum, otherwise it won't fit on 3.5in, but on 5.5in, it needs to be full height

Comment: If you need a different layout for different size screens you can use size classes.  Change your size class from Any Any to whatever size you need it to be and then set constraints for that as well.  Whichever size is being used it will use those constraints.  That can be found at the bottom center of your storyboard view, inline with the constraint tools.